# foundation 3 sass not compiling

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, compass-sass, zurb-foundation

Up until recently my SaSS has been compiling without a hitch, earlier tonight I started to get the following errors.

I have tried rejigging my Gemfile, but I can not for the live of me workout how to get the files to compile and serve the correct css.

```
Started GET "/assets/application.css" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-03-11 21:27:35 +1100
Error compiling asset application.css:
Sass::SyntaxError: File to import not found or unreadable: foundation/common/ratios.
Load paths:
  Sass::Rails::Importer(/Users/paulmcguane/Sites/Rails/teammngt/app/assets/stylesheets/app.css.scss)
  /Users/paulmcguane/Sites/Rails/teammngt/app/assets/stylesheets
  /Users/paulmcguane/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/blueprint/stylesheets
  /Users/paulmcguane/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/gems/compass-0.12.2/frameworks/compass/stylesheets
  Compass::SpriteImporter
  (in /Users/paulmcguane/Sites/Rails/teammngt/app/assets/stylesheets/app.css.scss)
Served asset /application.css - 500 Internal Server Error
```

gem file

```
    source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.3'
gem 'therubyracer', :platform => :ruby

gem 'better_errors'

# Database Gems
gem 'yaml_db'
gem 'thin'
gem 'pg'
gem 'rb-readline'


#Application Processing
gem 'haml'
gem 'json'
gem 'spreadsheet'
gem 'paperclip'

#Phone conversion
gem 'countries'
gem 'phony'
gem 'phony_rails'

#Application required gems
gem 'zurb-foundation'
gem 'twilio-ruby'
gem 'simple-navigation', '~> 3.7.0'
gem 'kaminari'
gem 'client_side_validations'
gem 'event-calendar', :require => 'event_calendar'
gem 'watu_table_builder', :require => 'table_builder'
gem 'best_in_place'
gem 'to_xls', :git => 'https://github.com/dblock/to_xls.git', :branch => 'to-xls-on-models'


#Auth and Management
gem 'devise'
gem 'cancan'
gem 'switch_user'
gem 'paper_trail', '~> 2'
gem 'omniauth-facebook'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'
gem 'fb_graph'
#gem 'announcements'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'

  # Add these gems
  gem 'compass-rails'
  gem 'zurb-foundation'
end



gem 'jquery-rails'
gem 'compass'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Judging from the look of your gemfile, you're not specifying a version of zurb-foundation.

**The short answer is**, specify `gem 'zurb-foundation', '= 3.2.5'` in your gemfile instead.

Otherwise, if you've run a bundle update anytime recently, your zurb-foundation gem has upgraded to 4.x which does not include a path to foundation/common/ratios anymore.

I was banging my head against the wall with this on Heroku, which I talk about in [Avoid a Headache: Precompiling Zurb (Foundation) on Heroku](http://eric-schaefer.com/blog/2013/04/24/rails-zurb-foundation-import-heroku/)